# browser control at any time using Nightmare or Puppeteer or something else

Tags: node.js

I want to log into a specific site using nightmarejs or puppeteer or something else. And leave the browser and this site open, and at any time access this site and do various operations there, for example, click on a certain div, and then take text information from the window that appears. And what I will do will depend on the contents of the file that I will check for changes, and if there are changes, depending on the contents of the file, I will do some operations on the site, and the file may change after 10 seconds, and then, for example, after 2 minutes and so on. So, is it possible to somehow implement this with the help of at least some nodejs package: nightmare, puppeteer, whatever, just to work. So far, nothing has worked for me.

```
 
 const watch = require('node-watch')
const fs = require("fs");
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');     
(async ()=>{
let nightmare; 
try {
    nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
    await nightmare
        .goto('https://example.com')
        .type('input#username', 'username')
        .type('input#password', 'password')
        .click('input#button')
          .wait(5000);
        watch('hello.txt', function(event, filename) {
  console.log(filename, ' changed.')
  let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("hello.txt", "utf8");
  if(fileContent === 1){
  let sit1 = await nightmare.evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelector('.class1').textContent;
        });
        console.log(sit1)
  }else if(fileContent === 2){
  let sit2 = await nightmare.evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelector('.class2').textContent;
        console.log(sit2)   
        }); 
  
  }
})

    
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
} 
})();
```

Of course, the code does not work even close, and most likely for understanding people it will be even funny, but I am not a professional programmer, I just write programs for myself.
And I posted the code for a rough understanding of what I want to do.

Comment: Depending on the specifics of what you're trying to do, you might be better off making use of the developer tools and connecting them as-needed.  Alternatively, if you don't need programmatic control, maybe just run an Xorg server and connect to it when needed?

Comment: I'm sorry for question, but where can I get these developer tools and how can I connect to them using node.js? I just don't understand much about it.

Comment: They're built into the browser.  You can press F12.  But, you can also run it remote:  https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html  Puppeteer actually uses this protocol, so maybe it has an option for connecting remotely too.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Most likely this will not work for me, because the information that I receive I send to the electron application, and also I need a couple of browsers to be open in headless mode like in nightmare or puppeteer.